# Why is <p> ending up in another <div> when applying padding, instead of expanding div its in?

Tags: html, css, css-float

Why is `<p>` ending up in another `<div>` when applying padding, instead of expanding div its in?

Here is my code. Ultimately, I am trying to add some padding to the `<p>` element to push it down, but within its div.

I will have a button at top right, and I want text below it, but not covered by the button. Button will be z-index:999 and relative position to its div.

edit: this is how complete code should look, trying to contain content. Clearfix isnt working here, button has z-index:1 so should be on top?

```css
  .clearfix::after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    clear: both;
  }
  
  .header {
    background-color: bisque;
  }
  
  .wrap {
    max-width: 960px;
  }
  
  .content h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 0px;
  }
  
  .content p {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 0px;
  }
  
  .button {
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    float: right;
  }
```

```html
<header class="header ">
  <div class="wrap clearfix">
    <div class="content ">
      <h1>left</h1>
      <p>right</p>
      <a href="#" class="button">button</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the elements are floated, and the parents need to "clear" the floats so that the elements don't appear outside of the parent. You can look up CSS "clearfix" techniques to get a clear illustration of the issue and ways to address it.

I added a new `.clearfix` class with a popular technique for clearing floated children.

```css
.clearfix::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}

.first {
    background-color: bisque;
  }
  
  .first h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
  
  .first p {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  
  .second {
    background-color: grey;
  }
  
  .third {
    background-color: teal;
  }
```

```html
<div class="first clearfix">
      <h1>I expand "first" div with padding</h1>
      <p>I do not expand, I am outside "first" div. End up on top of another div... Why?? </p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="second">
      <p>section 2 text</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="third">
      <p>section 3 text</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: More importantly, float: right causes display: inline-block to have no effect. Perhaps the asker is expecting the padding to apply as a result of the latter, but since floating blockifies an element, that display declaration becomes altogether irrelevant.

Comment: @BoltClock for sure, I wouldn't say it's more important though, I think their positioning to `float: right;` the element means they want it on the right, and `inline-block` isn't going to do that. They're just interested in why the element is appearing outside of it's parent instead of affecting it's parent with padding declarations. I'd just say,  like you also said, their current `display` declaration is irrelevant, so I didn't mention it.

Comment: Appreciate the heads up about display. The correct way is to float left and right, no reason to display inline-block I guess?

Comment: @AlexArt well, if you `float` an element, no need to set a `display` attribute, because the element will be `display: block;` because of the `float`, so your `display` declaration becomes irrelevant and unnecessary/unused.

Comment: @MichaelCoker, new problem, maybe you can help fix this. I thought I had it figured out, but apparently not. I edited the original code, can you look? The button should be all the way to right on top of the text as it has z-index:1..

Comment: @AlexArt it's bad etiquette to change the post and seek help with new issues after you've accepted an answer. If you have a new problem, you should make a new post.

Comment: @MichaelCoker, I apologize. Not my intention to offend anyone, I will make a new post.

Comment: @AlexArt no worries! Just letting you know. It kind of goes against the goal of SO. The purpose is not just to solve your problems, but to provide a place with specific problems and answers to those problems, so that 5 years from now someone can search for this issue, find your question, and the solutions. Once you've accepted an answer, you're very unlikely to get anyone else to look at the question, and it may not be something I can solve if you hit me up personally (like you did here). So if you change the question after you've accepted an answer, all of the current answers...

Comment: @AlexArt ... will be about your original question, and I may not have a solution, meaning it's no longer something someone can search for, and find your original question, and all of the answers in the post will be about the original question. It's far better for you (in terms of getting people to answer) and the community as a whole if you 1) ask a single, clear question in your post, 2) upvote and accept good answers, and 3) don't change your question or go through the comments to seek out additional/new help.

Comment: @MichaelCoker, agreed. I realize that after I changed the question. Thanks for being patient, taking the time to explain and not jumping all over me about it! That type of attitude is why make me say this community is great!

Answer (score 0):

```
.first p {
  float: right;  // remove this
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
```

Just remove `float: right` from your code.

Answer (score 0):

its the clearfix problem you can google it .

when a child is floated parent doesnt contain it thats why your p tag goes out.

```css
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

.first {
    background-color: bisque;
  }
  
  .first h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
  
  .first p {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  
  .second {
    background-color: grey;
  }
  
  .third {
    background-color: teal;
  }
```

```html
<div class="first cf">
      <h1>I expand "first" div with padding</h1>
      <p>I do not expand, I am outside "first" div. End up on top of another div... Why?? </p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="second">
      <p>section 2 text</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="third">
      <p>section 3 text</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks. Ill have to learn some more about this, wasn't able to find the answer, because I didn't know the correct question to Google.. hah. But now I do.